# Correct way of hiding a view using an animation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-view

I've tried several ways of hiding a view and then removing it from the parent layout:

1. Call an alpha fade animation followed by a call to setVisibility(GONE);
2. Call an alpha fade animation followed by a call to setVisibility(GONE) inside of the AnimationListener
3. Call an alpha fade animation followed by removing the parent layout inside of the AnimationListener.

Each time, the resulting animation fails --- the view disappears twice from the screen.  The alpha fade animation works fine but when you change the visibility or remove it from the parent view, it quickly reappears again before disappearing a second time. The result is an unexpected jittery animation.

Example code:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AddTaskActivity.this,
            R.anim.fade_out);
final LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addtask_root);
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    parentView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                        parentView.removeView(test);
                }
    });
    }
```

That animation fails---the test view disappears twice from view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

<s>I ***guess*** that if you transparent your view before remove it or change it's visibility,you can do what you want:</s>

```
@Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    parentView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                        // transparent your view
                        ...     
                        parentView.removeView(test);
                }
    });
```

**Edit:**

I saw android documentation in about animations and it says:

> Another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only
>   modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. For
>   instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the
>   button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click
>   the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to
>   handle this.
>
> With the property animation system, these constraints are completely
>   removed, and you can animate any property of any object (Views and
>   non-Views) and the object itself is actually modified. The property
>   animation system is also more robust in the way it carries out
>   animation. At a high level, you assign animators to the properties
>   that you want to animate, such as color, position, or size and can
>   define aspects of the animation such as interpolation and
>   synchronization of multiple animators.

So I guess that you have to use **`property animation`**.

Comment: Nope. Tried this too. The problem is that after the fade_out animation finishes it immediately makes the view visible again for a split second causing the jitteriness.